# Login user using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following problem, in my application I would like to have some kind of login. I have following code: (Inspiration here on the web)

```
public boolean login(String username, String password)
    {
       try{
            EntityTransaction entr=em.getTransaction();
            entr.begin();

        TypedQuery<Users> query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM users u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :pass", Users.class);        
        query.setParameter(1, username);
        query.setParameter(2, password); 
        try{ 
            Users u = query.getSingleResult();
            return true;
        }catch(javax.persistence.NoResultException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
        finally{
        em.close();
        }

    }
```

When I run it and try to log in, the console will write the following message:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT u FROM users u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :pass]. 
[14, 19] The abstract schema type 'users' is unknown.
[28, 35] The state field path 'u.login' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
[49, 59] The state field path 'u.password' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

This is my table:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dke.ps.Tables;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author michal
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserid", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = :userid")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLogin", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.login = :login")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password = :password")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.email = :email")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByDate", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.date = :date")})
public class Users implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private Integer userid;
    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userid")
    private Collection<Saves> savesCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "saveid", referencedColumnName = "saveid")
    @ManyToOne
    private Saves saveid;

    public Users() {
    }

    public Users(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public Integer getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<Saves> getSavesCollection() {
        return savesCollection;
    }

    public void setSavesCollection(Collection<Saves> savesCollection) {
        this.savesCollection = savesCollection;
    }

    public Saves getSaveid() {
        return saveid;
    }

    public void setSaveid(Saves saveid) {
        this.saveid = saveid;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (userid != null ? userid.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
            return false;
        }
        Users other = (Users) object;
        if ((this.userid == null && other.userid != null) || (this.userid != null && !this.userid.equals(other.userid))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.dke.ps.Tables.Users[ userid=" + userid + " ]";
    }

}
```

As you can see, the "users" table really exists. I have no idea why it says to me, "The abstract schema type 'users' is unknown.".

Can you help me? I think the other two errors are caused by the first one.

Comment: You show us a class,  _not_ a table. The table is found in the database. Can you confirm it is there?

Comment: What is your purpose for doing this, by the way--learning/academic or for a real project?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's there. This is my SQL query: CREATE TABLE users
(
  userid integer NOT NULL,
  saveid integer,
  login character varying,
  password character varying,
  email character varying,
  date date,
  CONSTRAINT "User_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (userid),
  CONSTRAINT "Save_saveid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (saveid)
      REFERENCES saves (saveid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

Comment: Learning/academic project :) This method should return TRUE if the username and password are correct (I mean, if the user really login the correct username password)

Comment: I'm not sure, but... You use named parameters in your query; shouldn't your setters need to use names too? I mean `query.setParameter("login", username);` instead of `query.setParameter(1, username);`?

Comment: Okay, but at this moment, whatever I write to the login form, informs me that I have been logged in (so it does not seem to be validating from the database if the user is really there)

Comment: How about setting a query like `TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(u) FROM Users u WHERE ...", Long.class);` and check how many result(s) you have. It may give you some hint (was your query wrong? was the input wrong? etc)
Off topic but AFAIK, it's recommend to name your entities / table in database without plural. It feels strange to read `User*s* u = query.get*Single*Result();`

Comment: I just try this - String sql = "SELECT COUNT(d.userid) FROM Users d";
        Query q = em.createQuery(sql);
        long count = (long)q.getSingleResult();
        System.out.println(count); And it return 3 results (thats correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception relates to JPQL query compiling, JPQL syntax expect entity names instead table names, try changing your query to the following:

```
SELECT u FROM **Users** u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :pass
```

Comment: I just tried it and wrote it to me this - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter at position 1 which does not exist in this query string SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :pass.

Comment: This appears because you using named parameters,you need set theirs name in setParameter method (there is overloaded variant with String as argument) or you can change your query using indexed parameters. http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/parameter

Comment: How do I set theirs name in setParameter method? If in this time I dont know it yet...?

Comment: like that:  query.setParameter("login", username) instead query.setParameter(1, username)

Comment: Okay, but at this moment, whatever I write to the login form, informs me that I have been logged in (so it does not seem to be validating from the database if the user is really there)